# How can I sum the amount of items in an array over time from a column in Hive partitions?

Tags: hive, presto

I am trying to add together the instances of multiple tags within an array in a column.

Table Name: Task_Queue

Partition 1

| item_id | category | task_tags | created_time | completed_time | date_stamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4562 | alert | windows, secevent, manual | 2022-1-1 | 0 | 2022-7-29 |
| 4563 | event | linux, opsevent, manual | 2022-2-10 | 0 | 2022-7-29 |
| 4564 | alert | windows, secevent, manual | 2022-2-11 | 0 | 2022-7-29 |
| 4565 | event | mac, secevent, manual | 2022-2-16 | 0 | 2022-7-29 |
| 4585 | alert | windows, opsevent, manual | 2022-3-13 | 0 | 2022-7-29 |
| 4692 | event | linux, secevent, manual | 2022-3-14 | 0 | 2022-7-29 |
| 4662 | alert | mac, event, manual | 2022-5-5 | 0 | 2022-7-29 |
| 4673 | event | linux, secevent, manual | 2022-5-15 | 0 | 2022-7-29 |
| 4854 | alert | mac, secevent, manual | 2022-5-16 | 0 | 2022-7-29 |
| 4955 | event | linux, ide-event, manual | 2022-5-17 | 0 | 2022-7-29 |
| 4965 | alert | windows, secevent, manual | 2022-6-1 | 0 | 2022-7-29 |
| 4972 | event | mac, secevent, manual | 2022-6-10 | 0 | 2022-7-29 |

Partition 2

| item_id | category | task_tags | created_time | completed_time | date_stamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4462 | alert | windows, opsevent, manual | 2021-1-1 | 0 | 2022-6-29 |
| 4463 | event | linux, opsevent, manual | 2021-2-10 | 0 | 2022-6-29 |
| 4464 | alert | windows, opsevent, manual | 2021-2-11 | 0 | 2022-6-29 |
| 4465 | event | mac, secevent, manual | 2021-2-16 | 0 | 2022-6-29 |
| 4485 | alert | windows, opsevent, manual | 2021-3-13 | 0 | 2022-6-29 |
| 4492 | event | linux, opsevent, manual | 2021-3-14 | 0 | 2022-6-29 |
| 4462 | alert | mac, event, manual | 2021-5-5 | 0 | 2022-6-29 |
| 4473 | event | linux, event, manual | 2021-5-15 | 0 | 2022-6-29 |
| 4454 | alert | mac, opsevent, manual | 2021-5-16 | 0 | 2022-6-29 |
| 4455 | event | linux, ide-event, manual | 2021-5-17 | 0 | 2022-6-29 |
| 4465 | alert | windows, secevent, manual | 2021-6-1 | 0 | 2022-6-29 |
| 4472 | event | mac, opsevent, manual | 2021-6-10 | 0 | 2022-6-29 |

My query:

```sql
SELECT 
ds, 
COUNT(task_tags) AS "Total Tags)
FROM task_queue
WHERE completed_time = 0
AND task_tags CONTAIN('secevent', 'opsevent' 'ide-event)
GROUP BY ds
ORDER BY ds DESC
```

The result should be a trend of the total count of those tags above per partition in our data store. For the partition provided, the count would be 11 (4662 is not counted as 'event' is not needed)

Edit: Added all columns and created a second partition. Goal is to find a trend of task tags over time by identifying one of the varchar tags 'secevent', 'opsevent', 'ide-event'.  `

Comment: Your query contains some lexical errors and uses columns not present in sample data. Please add correct sample data and desired results.

Comment: Also what is the result of `select typeof(task_tags) from task_queue`? Is it varchar?